# Can i use a Pre workout and after my routine is done drink my mass gainer

Tags: workout, protein, pre-workout

I'm 17 and have been working out for about a year but in the recent months i started seeing the progress.

I'm a skinny guy and i began to take a mass gainer and a few days ago after my instructor gave me a pre workout sample and my workout felt significantly better.

I went to buy a box of pre workout and after my workouts i also drink my mass gainer muscle tech.

Answer (score 2):

Both of those items are supplements, meaning they supplement (add to) your diet to fill in the gaps.

- Pre-Workout is for providing you with energy required to workout harder (and potentially: have a bigger pump, recover faster, synthesise muscle mass better)
- Mass Gainer is just that, it is a powder containing lots of calories, usually in a lean, high protein, form.

## As both are supplements, you are fine to take both alongside a nutritionally rich diet.

**HOWEVER you should know what is in your powders**. Hopefully, you wouldn't just eat anything you were given by a stranger and especially not if it is in powder form.

The website you can look up MOST powders on is labdoor.com

- https://labdoor.com/rankings/pre-workout
- https://labdoor.com/rankings/protein

Here are some of the labdoor articles for MuscleTech's products,
I am going to go out on a limb and guess that your pre-workout is the same brand as your mass gainer (muscle tech).

- https://labdoor.com/review/muscletech-nitro-tech
- https://labdoor.com/review/muscletech-phase8
- https://labdoor.com/review/muscletech-nano-vapor

For example:

> In a surprising finding, MuscleTech NITRO-TECH contained over 1000mg
> of taurine, or more than 2x the taurine content in a Red Bull. In
> known clinical trials, Taurine content of 1000-9000mg has been
> analyzed for energy; early data is positive but inconclusive.

Comment: I have the Mucle tech MASS TECH  and the PRE workout is B NoX and I have a diet also

Comment: I also have another question in the b nox bottle says take on empty stomach does it afects if I eat like 1 to 2 hours before going to the gym?